# Parse JSON to array in a shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON object within a shell script into an array.

e.g.: [Amanda, 25, http://mywebsite.com]

The JSON looks like:

```
{
  "name"       : "Amanda", 
  "age"        : "25",
  "websiteurl" : "http://mywebsite.com"
}
```

I do not want to use any libraries, it would be best if I could use a regular expression or grep. I have done:

```
myfile.json | grep name
```

This gives me "name"       : "Amanda". I could do this in a loop for each line in the file, and add it to an array but I only need the right side and not the entire line.

Comment: Use `jq` for this.

Comment: Have a look at [\[ this \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177843/parse-one-field-from-an-json-array-into-bash-array) question and show us some effort on your part to solve this.

Comment: This `cat myfile.json | grep name | cut -d ':' -f2` might help.

Comment: @sjsam: The accepted answer to the linked question demonstrates `jq` use well, but uses a misguided approach to reading its output into a shell array (as least as of this writing - comment posted).

Comment: I'm assuming instead of `[Amanda, 25, http://mywebsite.com]` you meant `( "Amanda" 25 "http://mywebsite.com")`; the latter is what bash's array syntax actually looks like. (Or, as given with `declare -p array`, this could also be printed as follows: `declare -a array='([0]="Amanda" [1]="25" [2]="http://mywebsite.com")'`)

Comment: ...if you want isn't a bash array but some other language's idea of an array, the question should make that explicit.

Comment: @sjsam, ...btw, thank you for the pointer -- I made an effort to add a non-buggy (well, less-buggy; still can't handle embedded newlines in content, but all our answers here have the same problem) answer to the question you linked.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you really cannot use a proper JSON parser such as [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)<sup>[1]</sup>
, try an **`awk`-based solution**:

Bash 4.x:

```
readarray -t values < <(awk -F\" 'NF>=3 {print $4}' myfile.json)
```

Bash 3.x:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra values < <(awk -F\" 'NF>=3 {print $4}' myfile.json)
```

This stores all property *values* in Bash array `${values[@]}`, which you can inspect with
`declare -p values`.

These solutions have limitations:

- each property must be on its own line,
- all values must be double-quoted,
- embedded escaped double quotes are not supported.

All these limitations reinforce the recommendation to use a proper JSON parser.

---

<sup>Note: The following alternative solutions use the Bash 4.x+ `readarray -t values` command, but they also work with the Bash 3.x alternative, `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra values`.</sup>

**`grep` + `cut` combination**: A single `grep` command won't do (unless you use *GNU* `grep` - see below), but adding `cut` helps:

```
readarray -t values < <(grep '"' myfile.json | cut -d '"' -f4)
```

---

***GNU* `grep`**: Using `-P` to support PCREs, which support `\K` to drop everything matched so far (a more flexible alternative to a look-behind assertion) as well as look-ahead assertions (`(?=...)`):

```
readarray -t values < <(grep -Po ':\s*"\K.+(?="\s*,?\s*$)' myfile.json)
```

---

Finally, here's a **pure Bash (3.x+) solution**:

<sup>What makes this a viable alternative in terms of performance is that *no external utilities are called in each loop iteration*; however, for larger input files, a solution based on external utilities will be much faster.</sup>

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a values # declare the array                                                                                                                                                                  

# Read each line and use regex parsing (with Bash's `=~` operator)
# to extract the value.
while read -r line; do
  # Extract the value from between the double quotes
  # and add it to the array.
  [[ $line =~ :[[:blank:]]+\"(.*)\" ]] && values+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
done < myfile.json                                                                                                                                          

declare -p values # print the array
```

---

<sup>[1] Here's what **a robust `jq`-based solution** would look like (Bash 4.x):

`readarray -t values < <(jq -r '.[]' myfile.json)`</sup>

Answer (score 4):

jq is good enough to solve this problem

```
paste -s <(jq '.files[].name' YourJsonString) <(jq '.files[].age' YourJsonString) <( jq '.files[].websiteurl' YourJsonString)
```

So that you get a table and you can grep any rows or awk print any columns you want

Comment: OP literally said no libraries, there are a million other questions with JQ as the answer already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a sed one liner to achieve this:

```
array=( $(sed -n "/{/,/}/{s/[^:]*:[[:blank:]]*//p;}" json ) )
```

Result:

```
$ echo ${array[@]}
"Amanda" "25" "http://mywebsite.com"
```

If you do not need/want the quotation marks then the following sed will do away with them:

```
array=( $(sed -n '/{/,/}/{s/[^:]*:[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p;}' json) )
```

Result:

```
$ echo ${array[@]}
Amanda 25 http://mywebsite.com
```

It will also work if you have multiple entries, like

```
$ cat json
{
  "name"       : "Amanda" 
  "age"        : "25"
  "websiteurl" : "http://mywebsite.com"
}

{
   "name"       : "samantha"
   "age"        : "31"
   "websiteurl" : "http://anotherwebsite.org"
}

$ echo ${array[@]}
Amanda 25 http://mywebsite.com samantha 31 http://anotherwebsite.org
```

UPDATE:

As pointed out by mklement0 in the comments, there might be an issue if the file contains embedded whitespace, e.g., `"name" : "Amanda lastname"`. In this case `Amanda` and `lastname` would both be read into seperate array fields each. To avoid this you can use `readarray`, e.g.,

```
readarray -t array < <(sed -n '/{/,/}/{s/[^:]*:[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p;}' json2)
```

This will also take care of any globbing issues, also mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Please don't parse command output into an array with `array=( $(...) )` (even though it happens to work with the sample input): it doesn't work as intended with embedded whitespace and can result in accidental globbing.

Comment: @mklement0 Can you give an example of how the contents of sample file would have to look like for an accidental globbing to occur?

Comment: To see what your approach does to embedded whitespace, examine the array that results from `array=( $(echo '  a     b   ') )`; to see the effects of accidental globbing, try `array=( $(echo 'a * is born') )`.

Comment: For simplicity, try `"*"` as the JSON property value; focusing on the JSON is a distraction, though, as my `echo` commands are sufficient to demonstrate the problem: the output from the command substitution, _whatever the specific command happens to be_, is invariably subject to word splitting and globbing. The larger point is: reading items into an array this way is an _antipattern_ that is best avoided altogether. (You could work around the issues with `IFS=` and `set -f`, but at that point it's simpler to use `readarray`.)

Comment: @mklement0 I am not sure why the globbing did not match anything previously. Probably because I  manipulated `IFS` during testing at some point. However, after restarting the shell the globbing did actually happen. I will update my answer to address this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider editing your correction to actually flow with the answer rather than being an addendum at the end; otherwise, someone trying to follow this answer is more likely to use the buggy code than not.

Comment: (`echo ${array[@]}` is also bad form -- even if `array=( "Hello" "Test * Example" "World" )`, it won't print that as three separate elements despite the contents being correctly stored that way. Consider `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"`, *with the quotes*).

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash 3.x+ without dependencies (such as jq, python, grep, etc.):

```
source <(curl -s -L -o- https://github.com/lirik90/bashJsonParser/raw/master/jsonParser.sh)
read -d '' JSON << EOF
{
  "name"       : "Amanda", 
  "age"        : "25",
  "websiteurl" : "http://mywebsite.com"
}
EOF

JSON=$(minifyJson "$JSON")
name=$(parseJson "$JSON" name)
age=$(parseJson "$JSON" age)
url=$(parseJson "$JSON" websiteurl)
echo "Result: [$name,$age,$url]"
```

Output:

```
Result: [Amanda,25,http://mywebsite.com]
```

[Try it](https://replit.com/@lirik90/bashJsonParser-38364261).