# Parse JSON Response to extract specific values Bash with out using any utility

Tags: linux, bash

I tried using [Parse JSON to array in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364261/parse-json-to-array-in-a-shell-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but unable to get required field. Below is my json:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "databaseHealthCheck": 
    {
        "status": "UP",
        "dataSource": 
        {
            "maxActive": 100,
            "maxIdle": 8,
            "numActive": 0,
            "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/db_name",
            "userName": "test_123"
        }
    },

    "JMSHealthCheck": 
    {
        "status": "UP",
        "producerTemplate": 
        {
            "name": "Test_2",
            "pendingCount": 0,
            "operator": "<"
        }
    },

    "diskSpace": 
    {
        "status": "UP",
        "total": 414302519296,
        "free": 16099868672,
        "threshold": 10485760
    }
}
```

I want to extract pendingCount value under producerTemplate under JMSHealthCheck.

Have restriction to use utility like jq.

Bash Version 3.x

Comment: You should hire a programmer. Seriously, you haven't even shown any effort to solve your homework problem yourself. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In absence of `jq`, you may use this `gnu grep` command:

```
read -r s < <(grep -zoP '"JMSHealthCheck":\s*{[^{}]*?"producerTemplate":\s*{[^{}]*?"pendingCount":\h*\K\d+' file.json)

echo "$s"
```

```
0
```

However, please keep in mind that parsing a JSON using regex is not recommended. If you have `jq` then it would be a very simple `jq` command lke this:

```
jq '.JMSHealthCheck.producerTemplate.pendingCount' file.json
```

Comment: json_parsing.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
json_parsing.sh: line 17: `read -r s < <(grep -zoP '"JMSHealthCheck":\s*{[^{}]*?"producerTemplate":\s*{[^{}]*?"pendingCount":\h*\K\d+' myfile.json)'

Comment: First check output of `grep -zoP '"JMSHealthCheck":\s*{[^{}]*?"producerTemplate":\s*{[^{}]*?"pendingCount":\h*\K\d+' myfile.json`. Error you are getting is because you're not using `bash`

Comment: grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined using bash already

Comment: [See this working demo with same command](https://ideone.com/WhtmjU). Check your `grep`  version. As I mentioned it requires `gnu grep`